# Can a MySQL connector be shared between objects?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I'm using MySQL Connector/Python. I have an object that generates objects, and some of those objects generate more objects. At the moment, I'm ending up with around 300 total objects. Given the way I have it set up, that means 300 database connections. Is it possible to connect once and simply pass the connection around?

I envision it looking something like this:

```
class MyObject(dict):
    def __init__(self, row, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        # pass the connection/cursor on to some more objects

def getObjects(query, args):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="password", host="localhost", port="12345", database="database")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, args)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    myObjects = []
    while rowDict is not None:
        myObj = MyObject(row, conn)
        myObjects.append(myObj)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return myObjects
```

But when I implement it in this way, I get `InternalError: Unread result found.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think the answer is: **use pools**. Once I implemented connection pooling, I got my connections down from 300 to 10. It basically looks like this:

```
def getConnectionPool():
    config = {
                "user":"user", 
                "password":"password", 
                "host":"localhost", 
                "port":"12345", 
                "database":"database"
              }
    pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="MyPool", pool_size=10, **config)
    return pool

def getAllObjects():
    pool = getConnectionPool()
    newObject = NewObject(pool)

class NewObject(object):
    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.conn = pool.get_connection()
        # cursor, etc.
```